# A failure occurred while executing jetpack compose test case

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, junit4, dagger-hilt

I am facing issue while running the test case my test case look like below:

`@HiltAndroidTest
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class LoginScreenTest {

```
/**/
@get:Rule
val hiltRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)


lateinit var loginViewModel: LoginAuthViewModel
@get:Rule
val composeTestRule = createComposeRule()

@Before
fun setup() {
    // Set up your mock ViewModel to return predefined values or behaviors

    composeTestRule.setContent {
        loginViewModel = hiltViewModel()
        val navController = mock(NavController::class.java)
        LoginNewScreen(navController = navController)
    }
}
@Test
fun testLogin_Success() {}
```

}

while running the above code i am facing the error like below

Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugAndroidTestKotlin'.

> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

I am not able to figure out what exactly the root couse for this if i run the app withought the test case that work fine.

dependecy:

//test part
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:1.6.0-alpha01")
testImplementation("org.mockito:mockito-core:3.12.4")
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:2.13.0'
androidTestImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-android:3.12.4'

```
androidTestImplementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing:1.0.1'
```

`